# Need to achieve proper ordering using order by and group by

Tags: postgresql

I have a database table named "super" :

```
   subclass     |     class      | show
----------------+----------------+------
 int1           |                | 1
 int2           |                | 1
 cmda           |  int2          | 1.1
 cmda           |  int1          | 1.1
 cmdb           |  map1          | 2.1
 map1           |                | 2
```

I am trying to group them according to their class column and show column

I need in this format:

```
  result        |   
----------------
 int1           |               
 cmda           |                
 int2           |  
 cmda           |  
 map1           | 
 cmdb           |
```

I tried to group all "subclass" under "class" using DB statement `GROUP BY` AND as well should be in order

So,I used here "ORDER BY".

MY QUERY:

```
SELECT * FROM super ORDER BY show and GROUP BY class;
```

But it is not returning the expected order.

Comment: Your first problem is that your listed statement will generate a syntax error.

Comment: ...this would be much easier if `show` actually used a unique number, starting from each top-level id.  What happens as you get more levels down (more nesting)?